# Reference CLR Triggers from the master database

Tags: sql, .net, sql-server, clr, sqlclr

I have created a CLR assembly on the master database of an SQL Server.

This assembly defines CLR Trigger functions and I want to attach these to tables in other databases on the server in an SQL statement.

Something like this:

```
USE myDb;
CREATE TRIGGER myTrigger ON myTable FOR INSERT,UPDATE,DELETE
AS EXTERNAL NAME [master].[dbo].myAssembly.TriggerClass.Report;
```

Is there a good way to get this to work?

Comment: I don't think that you can. I think CLR triggers have to be in an assembly added to the specific database (which at least stops breakage such as if a database is backed up from one server and restored on a different one, it's not then looking for resources that may not exist)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `EXTERNAL NAME` clause for all SQLCLR object types only allows for referencing Assemblies in the current database. The `database_name.schema_name.` portion that is in your example desired code in the Question is not valid syntax. You can see this on the MSDN page for CREATE TRIGGER at:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx

You will need to add the Assembly to any database that you want to use the Trigger in.

And, if you could reference Assemblies in other databases, you would still be better off creating a "Utility" database  (or some other name like Common, etc.) rather than adding objects to a system database :-).